# Runtime fatal error - possibly CLR bug

Tags: visual-studio, clr

I would like some insight into an error I'm receiving:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\app.exe'. Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error... This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of the user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack."

I would like to understand not only the error itself, but what/how CLR may play a part, and I've never really heard of COM-intercop or PInvoke are.. so some insight into those would also be helpful.

Also, the really odd part of it all is that if I continue through the breakpoints and **do not step into or over, I do not see the error**. However, if I **step through line by line, the error pops up**! Can anyone explain why I only see it while stepping through?

Not sure what other information would be useful.. please let me know (nicely of course!) what I could add.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Surprisingly it is happening for ONLY one of the projects in my solution. I've got a dozen of projects in my solution but all others run without any issue. The one in which I'm facing this issue is a C# console application. To add to info, I had taken a huge bulk of pending windows 7 update in the morning yesterday but if that would have been the root cause then it should have affected the startup pattern of all the projects in the solution. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. The issue happens only during debugging the project from VS. Its output exe from debug folder works perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely not a CLR bug, but probably a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug). We can't really say what's causing it, though, without seeing your code.

Try turning on [Managed Debugging Assistants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx) to figure out if some error or access violation is being suppressed.

Comment: The Managed Debugging Assistant is what caught it.. I will add that to the message. Sorry I forgot it!

Comment: Also, I'm looking to know what an CLR bug actually is (even if it isn't the case here...)

Comment: Hm... what do you mean by "what a CLR bug actually is"? Isn't it just a bug in the CLR?

Comment: Yea.. but I kinda know what CLR is, but not entirely.. like how would something I wrote manage to make the bug in the CLR appear? And why only when I step through?

Comment: @developer: Well, bugs aren't predictable. :) It might just happen to run into a special-case `if` statement in the CLR, and then make the bug appear. But, again, this is probably not the answer; feel confident that there is most likely no bug in the CLR that is causing your error.

Comment: @Mehrdad: so should I be concerned there is a bug in my own code? Not able to really pin point what could be causing it.. (yet anyways).

Comment: @developer: Yeah, the bug is most likely in your code. If you post the signature of the method, we might be able to figure out the problem. (Random guess, but do you have an interface with a method that returns an `HRESULT`? And if so, did you declare it as `int` or as `void`?)

Comment: Surprisingly it is happening for ONLY one of the projects in my solution. I've got a dozen of projects in my solution but all others run without any issue. The one in which I'm facing this issue is a C# console application. To add to info, I had taken a huge bulk of pending windows 7 update in the morning yesterday but if that would have been the root cause then it should have affected the startup pattern of all the projects in the solution. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. The issue happens only during debugging the project from VS. Its output exe from debug folder works perfect.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this working on a Dotnet Core project. I deleted the binaries and rebuilt, this fixed it for me. Simply doing a Clean and Build or just Rebuild had no effect.

Comment: I experienced the same. I deleted each bin and obj folder in each of my solution's projects. I noticed that deleting those folders using the windows explorer usually didn't completely clear them on the first try, so I ended up highlighting the folders, hitting delete, and repeating that process (deleting the folders a second time!) for each project. Then after a rebuild, debugging worked normally.

Answer (score 1):

This problem troubles me a lot too and I have not managed to find the cause, but I found a work around so I can at least continue doing my job.

For me, the problem occurs when I debug with F10 and F11 and I am exciting the method and that method returns to the feature file. So as a workaround i have put breakpoints to all the entries of the methods and when I reach the exit of the next method I go to the next on with F5, doing it that way it will not crash.

The problem seems to occur only when I return to the *.feature file from a method using F10 or F11.

I hope it helps, at least as a workaround, but I am really curious to know the actual cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same error. What I noticed that I have 2 completely identical projects (Both the same). One is having this problem. So I did notice in my Project Property--> Under Compile Menu--> On the top, Configuration was set to Release. I change it back to Active(Debug) and recompile.
Now it's working fine.
[click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI7lt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am going to tell you about my sad story in order for others not to be trapped again in same mistake, this happened to me in case where I was calling a native C++ API continuously inside an infinite loop thread and forgetting to stop the thread when needed, sometimes this error you mentioned was exploding or an read/write protected memory exception and even worse sometimes the whole application was simply just crashing :)

That's all folks.

Answer (score 0):

What actually helped me is to delete all breakpoints. Probably some of them were pointing to commented lines.